# Proving the Binomial theorem

Tags: binomial-theorem

I am trying to work through the proof I understand it until on this website http://www.mcs.sdsmt.edu/ecorwin/cs251/bin_thm/bin_thm.html :

Pascal's identity does not apply for $k = 0$ or for $k = n$. In our sum, this means we need to split out the $j = 0$ and $j = k + 1$ terms before applying Pascal's identity.

Why does k=o and k=n correspond to $j=0$ and $j=k+1$?

Now we have the problem of matching the two sums from the left side with the two from the right side. First, notice that the out front on the right side can be thought of as the $j = 0$ term in the first sum. Next, the y $k+1$ out front on the right side can be thought of as the $j = k + 1$ term in the second sum.

Why can you think of these terms equaling $j=0$ in the first sum, why not for the second sum? And the same for $j=k+1$?

Answer (score 1):

There are several proofs on the wikipedia page on the binomial theorem.

Later addition:  Regarding the proof you cited, Pascal's identity also holds for those endpoints $k=0$ and $k=n$ (all you have to do is define the binomial to be $0$ when $k>n$ or $k<0$).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/761821)

Comment: Would it be better to copy/paste an answer from wikipedia? But perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question:  It could mean: find a proof (OK), or it could mean, explain this particular proof (that I didn't do) (I now added something).

Comment: I would say it would be better not to answer questions which can be answered by lookup on wikipedia.And the question most likely is about explain this particular proof(reading the body of the question) and not in general how to prove the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Pascals Identity is: $\dbinom {k+1} j = \dbinom k{j-1}+\dbinom k j$

Now, if it applied at $j=0$ or $j=k+1$ we would need an evaluation for: $$\dbinom{k}{-1}=\dbinom k{k+1}=\dfrac{k!}{(-1)!~(k+1)!}$$

Okay, *by convention* this is *usually* taken as zero.   But *by definition* it includes a factor of the factorial of minus one, which is indefinite.   So they just... sidestepped the issue and explicitly evaluated the end terms, since *those* are uncontroversial.

$$\begin{align}\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} \binom{k+1}{j} x^{k+1-j}y^j ~ & = ~ \binom{k+1}0 x^{k+1}+\binom{k+1}{k+1} y^{k+1}+\sum_{j=1}^k \binom {k+1}j x^{k+1-j}y^j 
\\ & = ~ x^{k+1}+y^{k+1}+\sum_{j=1}^k\left[\binom{k}{j-1}+\binom{k}{j}\right]x^{k+1-j}y^j
\\ & \quad\vdots\quad \text{et cetera}
\end{align}$$